# how to access c:/windows/where.exe Flutter and Android Emulator (the-requested-operation-requires-elevation)

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, android-emulator, runtime-error

i am trying to make a gps app but i have a problem.
Emulator cannot access c:/windows/where.exe application during compilation.

I chose the Always run emulator as administrator option, still the same.

[image]